# JavaScript running light doesnt get the last element

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to have a running progress bar .My html looks like this

```js
var timer;
var index = 0;

window.onload = () => {
  var parent = document.querySelector("div");

  timer = window.setInterval(() => {

    var child = parent.children[index];
    child.className = "on";
    index++;
    if (index >= 4) {

      turnOff(0, parent);
      index = 0
    }
  }, 1000);
}

var turnOff = (i, parent) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var e = parent.children[i];
    e.className = "off";
  }
};

function disbaleme() {
  window.clearInterval(timer)
}
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}

.off {
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="off"></div>
    <div class="off"></div>
    <div class="off"></div>
    <div class="off"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <button onclick="disbaleme()">click</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

the issue is i can never get the last div element and set the className of it to on. Does anyone know what is going wrong here?
if i remove the turnOff method however it works just fine. im really confused

Comment: because you automatically remove it on the iteration you add it.

Comment: You increment `i` just before checking if it has reached 4. So, you'll call `turnOff` on the 4th iteration (index 3) and it immediately hides the third segment after it turned on. Move the increment below the `if` or change the condition to `i > 4`

Answer (score 0):

You remove the class as soon as you add it. You need to remove it on the next iteration. So move the check to the start of your function and reset the index there.

I added a return so it says empty for one second. If you do not want it to be empty, remove the return.

```js
var timer;
var index = 0;

window.onload = () => {
  var parent = document.querySelector("div");

  timer = window.setInterval(() => {
    if (index >= 4) {
      turnOff(0, parent);
      index = 0
      return; // remove the reuturn if you do not want it to be empty
    }
    var child = parent.children[index];
    child.className = "on";
    index++;
  }, 1000);

}
var turnOff = (i, parent) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var e = parent.children[i];
    e.className = "off";
  }
};

function disbaleme() {
  window.clearInterval(timer)
}
```

```css
.on {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}

.off {
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="off"></div>
  <div class="off"></div>
  <div class="off"></div>
  <div class="off"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The `turnOff()` function is not using the `i` parameter.

Comment: I did not see a need to alter it since it was working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

On the last tick, your function in `setInterval` is setting the className to `on` and then immediately setting everything to `off` again (with `turnOff`). Here is a version of your code that will only do one (turn last element on) or the other (turn all elements off), but not both. This I think brings you one step closer to what you're trying to do.

```js
var timer;
var index=0;

window.onload=()=>{
    var parent = document.querySelector("div");

    timer=window.setInterval(()=>{
        if(index>=4)
        {   
            turnOff(0,parent);
            index=0
        } else {
          var child=parent.children[index];
          child.className="on";
          index++;
        }
    },1000);

}
var turnOff=(i,parent)=>{
    for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        var e = parent.children[i];
        e.className="off";
    }};
function disbaleme(){
    window.clearInterval(timer)
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<style>
    .on{
        background-color: blue;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 2px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 2px;

    }
    .off{
        background-color: white;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 2px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 2px;

    }
</style>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="off"></div>
        <div class="off"></div>
        <div class="off"></div>
        <div class="off"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
<button onclick="disbaleme()">click</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also want to bring to your attention that the first parameter to your `turnOff` function is not being used. In this second snippet, I remove that parameter completely and the code works just the same.

```js
var timer;
var index = 0;

window.onload = () => {
  var parent = document.querySelector("div");

  timer = window.setInterval(() => {
    if(index >= 4) {   
      turnOff(parent);
      index = 0;
    } else {
      var child=parent.children[index];
      child.className="on";
      index++;
    }
  }, 1000);
};

var turnOff = (parent) => {
  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var e = parent.children[i];
    e.className="off";
  }
};

function disbaleme () {
  window.clearInterval(timer);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<style>
  .on{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
  }
  .off{
    background-color: white;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="off"></div>
    <div class="off"></div>
    <div class="off"></div>
    <div class="off"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <button onclick="disbaleme()">click</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```